# Faster way to store matrix elements in Python

Tags: python, performance

I'm writing code that's capturing a camera image as a numpy array, then breaks that into quadrants. My goal is to do this at video rates, so to take as little time as possible at every step. Right now, breaking into quadrants is one of my slow-downs (it takes 15 ms for a 4096x3000 image to be broken down). Is there a faster way to do this?

```
self.raw_img = frame

num_rows = int(self.raw_img.shape[0]/2.)
num_cols = int(self.raw_img.shape[1]/2.)

# Only initialize quadrant images one time
if self.quad_img == []:
    self.quad_img = np.zeros((4,num_rows,num_cols))

self.quad_img[0] = self.raw_img[:num_rows,:num_cols]
self.quad_img[1] = self.raw_img[num_rows:,:num_cols]
self.quad_img[2] = self.raw_img[:num_rows,num_cols:]
self.quad_img[3] = self.raw_img[num_rows:,num_cols:]
```

Comment: try to use `numpy.split`

Comment: Numpy indexing is very efficient. Creating slices with indexing does not actually copy the data but creates the view on the data in the memory. Take a look  here 
    https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html